# The constructor WsdlProject() refers to the missing type XmlException

Tags: web-services

This is my code written for creating soap client but it says The constructor WsdlProject() refers to the missing type XmlException.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlInterface;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlOperation;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject;
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wsdl.WsdlImporter;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.iface.Operation;

     WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
                WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "?wsdl");
                WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
                for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
                    WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
                    System.out.println("OP:" + op.getName());
                    System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
                    System.out.println("Response:");
                    System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
```

Answer (score 6):

Include jar files [xmlbeans](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.6.0) and [xmlbeans-xpath](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans-xpath/2.6.0) and surround your code with the following try-catch statement.

```
try {
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
                    WsdlInterface[] wsdls = WsdlImporter.importWsdl(project, "?wsdl");
                    WsdlInterface wsdl = wsdls[0];
                    for (Operation operation : wsdl.getOperationList()) {
                        WsdlOperation op = (WsdlOperation) operation;
                        System.out.println("OP:" + op.getName());
                        System.out.println(op.createRequest(true));
                        System.out.println("Response:");
                        System.out.println(op.createResponse(true));
    } 
    catch(XmlException e){
                //Your Code to handle exception.
            }
```